# Python - how to calculate a weighted average from dataframe using groupby and agg with lambda

Tags: python, lambda, average

I have a dataframe with the following columns:

['Year_of_Transaction_Date', 'Quarter_of_Transaction_Date',
'Month_of_Transaction_Date', 'Retailer_Name', 'Outlet_Display_Name',
'Product_Category_Name', 'Product_Sub_Category_Name',
'Retail_Product_Text', 'Actual_Sales_Qty', 'Actual_Sales_Value',
'Average_Unit_Price']

I want to create a summary of the data with total Sales Quantity and Weighted Average Price by Retailer Name & Product

Sampel of data is below:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQXh3.png)

I wrote the following code:

```
df_S10_June = (df.groupby(['Retailer_Name', 'Retail_Product_Text'], as_index = False)['Actual_Sales_Qty', 'Average_Unit_Price']
                     .agg({'Actual_Sales_Qty' : 'sum'
                           ,'Average_Unit_Price': lambda Average_Unit_Price : np.average(['Average_Unit_Price'], weights=['Actual_Sales_Qty'])
                          })
                  ).filter(items = ['Retailer_Name', 'Retail_Product_Text'
                                                     , 'Actual_Sales_Qty', 'Average_Unit_Price'])

df_S10_June
```

Expecting to get:

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNnbh.png)

But I'm getting the following error instead:

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (<class 'numpy.dtype[str_]'>, <class 'numpy.dtype[str_]'>) -> <class 'numpy.dtype[str_]'>